# Laravel "php artisan serv" works fine. Please Explain how artisan works

Tags: laravel

Please note that "php artisan serve" works fine. Also it works with wrong spelling for "serve" as "serv". Previously, Laravel used to hint that "Did you mean *php artisan serve*" Im not understanding how artisan works now. Please provide some sources to read about this.
This is the screenshot for my question.[image]

Comment: Also work with `php artisan ser`

Comment: But `php artisan se`  when trying with this can not identify which command to take because `session:table` and `serve` have a common first `se` two character, at finally `php artisan` auto-complete word of command like use `tab` key

Comment: Artisan is just php program that runs commands, how it works is not really relevant. The BadMethodCallSolutionProvider will handle this suggest with the `similar_text()` function. on the available methods of a class. If you really want to know.

Comment: Laravel is open source. If you are really curious about how it works then it will greatly benefit you if you just read the source code. I find it a relatively easy codebase to follow (most of the times)

Answer (score 1):

"php artisan serve" command is technical a simple Laravel command line command. You are able to create commands to. With the artisan command: php artisan make:command MyCommand` you can create a new commmand. which you can use over your cli.

How it works? I suggest that laravel iterate over some specific folders and read all files which extend the class `Illuminate\Console\Command;`. Then Laravel put all signature variables in an array.

Afterwards if you enter a command laravel would check the signture array with your input. Larvel would use some logics (maybe similar_text() what @GertB suggested in the comments) to find a command when you dont pass the entire command.

You are welcome to try the following. Create your own command. Enter "serv" in the signature. Then you will notice that you call your command with "php artisan serv" and no longer start the BuildIn server.

Comment: nicely explained, I have done some research in the past on how Laravel does this, so I could basically do the same thing in an app I was developing. It's a little more than just  similar_text(), but that briefly explains the logic.